# Headers lose styles after merging documents with Xceed Docx

Tags: c#, docx, xceed

Let me explain my scenario.

I am making use of Xceed Docx library to merge and manipulate word documents.
I have multiple templates that needs to be merged to form one customer facing document.
All of them having individual document headers, tables and images.

As per business requirements, we need to make use of content controls as there will be manual intervention.

PROBLEM:
All goes well and the merge works as expected, but it seems to drop the styling of the headers in merged document. But this only occurs when I include CONTENT CONTROLS (rich text content control)!

For example: `Header 1`, `Header 2` becomes `normal` text....

Has anyone experienced anything similar with this library?
Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try and contact the developers of DocX, with no avail.

I tried merging the files with [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) using AltChunk.
This did work but not to the extend that I required.

Let me explain. 
AltChunk inserts the entire file (doc2.docx) into the base file(doc1.docx)
and then only add reference of doc2 inside doc1's XML file.
Hope that makes sense.

MS Word can open this file, but when I want to make changes using DocX it is unable to load the file.

I ended up using [Docx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/) for all the document manipulation and [OpenXmlPowerTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools/) to merge the documents.

OpenXmlPowerTools seems to resolve the above mentioned issue as its does seem to do a complete image, chart and text merge.

I hope this helps someone in the near future ;-P